# Not able (anymore) to send GET or POST requests to a FB GROUP from MY PAGE which is ADMIN of the group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently, when we try to send GET or POST requests to a Fb GROUP with the access_token of a Fb PAGE that is also the ADMIN of the group, we get the error:

> *"{ "error": { "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'MY_GROUP_ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing
> permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph
> API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22),
> "type": "GraphMethodException", "code": 100, "error_subcode": 33,
> "fbtrace_id": "AKevVUU4GiTwPqINlHoNAMm" } }".*

**IT WORKED PERFECTLY UNTIL ABOUT A WEEK AGO:**

We have a script that POSTS automatically to the groups that we admin, by sending this request via CURL:

```
      $message_for_group = [
        'link' => 'https://www.example_domain.com/example_link,
        'message' => 'a message Caption'
      ];
      $accessToken = 'An_extended_token_(expires_never)_of_our_PAGE,_which_is_ADMIN_of_the_GROUP_that_we_try_to_post_to';


    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($message_for_group));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/'.$my_group_id.'/feed?method=post&access_token='.$accessToken);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36');
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $errors = curl_error($ch);
    $response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // if successful, it will be 200

    var_dump($response);
```

---

Additional INFO:

**WHEN I DEBUG THE PAGE ACCESS TOKEN with the Access Token Debugger from FB, It shows the following scopes:**

- email, manage_fundraisers, read_insights, publish_video, catalog_management, pages_manage_cta, pages_manage_instant_articles, pages_show_list, read_page_mailboxes, ads_management, ads_read, business_management, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_subscriptions, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments, instagram_manage_insights, instagram_content_publish, leads_retrieval, whatsapp_business_management, instagram_manage_messages, page_events, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_posts, pages_manage_engagement, whatsapp_business_messaging, instagram_shopping_tag_products, public_profile

---

**IF I TRY TO GENERATE ANOTHER ACCESS TOKEN in the Graph API Explorer, I can only select the following permissions (total of 30 permissions):**

- email,
  manage_fundraisers,
  read_insights,
  publish_video,
  catalog_management,
  pages_manage_cta,
  pages_manage_instant_articles,
  pages_show_list,
  read_page_mailboxes,
  ads_management,
  ads_read,
  business_management,
  pages_messaging,
  pages_messaging_subscriptions,
  instagram_basic,
  instagram_manage_comments,
  instagram_manage_insights,
  instagram_content_publish,
  leads_retrieval,
  whatsapp_business_management,
  instagram_manage_messages,
  page_events,
  pages_read_engagement,
  pages_manage_metadata,
  pages_read_user_content,
  pages_manage_ads,
  pages_manage_posts,
  pages_manage_engagement,
  whatsapp_business_messaging,
  instagram_shopping_tag_products,

---

**I WANT TO REITERATE THAT IT WORKED PERFEctLY UNTIL ABOUT A WEEK AGO...
AM I MISSING SOMETHING? WHAT DO YOU THINK I NEED TO DO IN ORDER TO MAKE IT WORK? THANKS!**

PS when we try to just GET the groups that our PAGE is a member of, using: https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/PAGE_ID/groups?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
we recieve a null reponse... no error, just a null array like this:

```
  {
     "data": [
  
     ]
  }
```

PLEASE HELP!